# R Subsetting a dataframe by date-range

Tags: r, date, dataframe, subset, date-range

I'd like to organize a dataframe by date-range.

Let's consider today is 1/1/2017 and the below table shows:

- Three types of product (Apple, Banana and Beer)
- Five expiry dates (1/15/2017, 2/27/2017, 3/15/2017, 9/1/2017 and 1/10/2018)

```
Product Type    1/15/2017   2/27/2017   3/15/2017   9/1/2017    12/20/2017  1/10/2018
Apple           3           10          -           2           8           -   
Banana          5           50          100         10          10          2 
Beer            1           1           1           1           1           1
```

You can read the above table as "the shop manager has 3 apples with an expiry date of 1/15/2017, 10 other apples that can last longer and have an expiry date of 2/27/2017 etc."

The shop manager is interested to know how many apples would expire in less than 1 month, in 1 to 3 months, in 3 to 12 months and in more than 12 months.

How can I code this in R please? 
The result table would look like this:

```
Product Type     Less than 1mth    1-3mths       3-12 mths       More than 12mths 
Apple            3                 10            10              -   
Banana           5                 150           20              2 
Beer             1                 2             2               1
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Have you made any attempts to code it yet? What are your ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data.table` answer:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(type=c("apple", "banana", "beer"), 
                 `2017-01-15`=c(3,5,1),
                 `2017-02-27`=c(10,50,1),
                 `2017-03-15`=c(NA, 100, 1),
                 `2017-09-01`=c(2,10,1),
                 `2017-12-20`=c(8,10,1),
                 `2018-01-10`=c(NA, 2, 1))

dt2 <- melt(dt, id.vars=c("type"))
dt2[, days_until_expires:=as.IDate(variable) - as.IDate("2017-01-01")]
dt2[, days_until_expires_f:=cut(days_until_expires, c(0, 30, 90, 360, Inf))]

out1 <- dt2[, list(N=sum(value, na.rm=T)), by=list(type, days_until_expires_f)]
out2 <- dcast(out1, type ~ days_until_expires_f, value.var="N")
```

`out2` is your output.

In the future, you can make it easier for users to help you by supplying a full Minimal Working Example (MWE). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve%20*here*) for guidance.

Answer (score 2):

A solution using function `tidyverse` and `lubridate`. `dt2` is the final output.

```
dt <- read.table(text = "'Product Type'    '1/15/2017'   '2/27/2017'   '3/15/2017'   '9/1/2017'    '12/20/2017'  '1/10/2018'
Apple           3           10          -           2           8           -   
                 Banana          5           50          100         10          10          2 
                 Beer            1           1           1           1           1           1",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, na.strings = "-")


library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

dt2 <- dt %>%
  gather(Date, Value, -Product.Type) %>%
  mutate(Date = sub("X", "", Date, fixed = TRUE)) %>%
  mutate(Date = mdy(Date)) %>%
  mutate(Day_Diff = Date - mdy("1/1/2017")) %>%
  mutate(Group = case_when(
    Day_Diff <= 30  ~ "Less than 1mth",
    Day_Diff <= 90  ~ "1-3mths",
    Day_Diff <= 361 ~ "3-12 mths",
    TRUE            ~ "More than 12mths"
  )) %>%
  group_by(Product.Type, Group) %>%
  summarise(Value = sum(Value, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  spread(Group, Value) %>%
  select(`Product Type` = Product.Type, `Less than 1mth`, `1-3mths`, 
         `3-12 mths`, `More than 12mths`)
```